# Union Data Power BI

Tags: powerbi, union

new to Power BI and just built a dashboard with some finance data with the following columns,

Date|Transaction ID|Transaction Amount|Item Description|Item Key

Every month I receive a new CSV file with data for the previous month. Rather than manually adding the new data to a master file each month, is there a way to simply drop the new CSV file into a folder each month and then refresh the dashboard so it automatically includes the new data (minus the headers)? If possible, I'd also like to add a column which holds the date the new file was loaded, so each new month's file is date stamped each time it's added.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use a folder as a source instead of a csv. 
That folder should contain all csv files.
When all your files are load you only have to select the following option:
[image]

After that you will have all the data from the all csv files in one gigant table.
Unfortunately its not possible to add a date column with the load date.
The only way to do that is that the csv files have the date column.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you save the file with the date in the filename, you can read the and extract the string with the date in it, saves adding the column

Comment: I would need the dates in a column I think, so it could be used as a filter on the dashboard. Also, when I union the cvs files, how do I stop Power BI including the headers of all of the different files? I just need the headers from the first file. Many thanks!

Comment: Since all your files should have the same header, you can filter the column name as a new step.